# Is it true that two isomorphic subgroups are in the same orbit (group acting on all its subgroups)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If two subgroups are in the same orbit (with group acting on all of its subgroups by conjugation), they are isomorphic. But is the reverse true?

Comment: No.  This would roughly say that all autos must be inner, which isn't so.

Comment: What autos and inner stands for? And what result are you citing?

Comment: Doesn't matter, due to TomGrubb's suggestion.  But, "automorphisms" and "inner automorphisms."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint: Conjugation in abelian groups is trivial.

Comment: LOL, amazingly simple.

Comment: A non-abelian example is $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, for a similar reason.